# Добавление объекта в массив объектов

Tags: java, массивы

у меня есть объект и мне нужно добавить его в массив объектов

```
// Считываю с клавиатуры mesta, station, vidprav, pribyt, freeMesta, day, numberReys
Cassa ca = new Cassa(mesta, station, vidprav, pribyt, freeMesta, day, numberReys); // мой объект
Cassa[] c = new Cassa[]{ca}; // массив объектов
```

Я считал данные и они теперь у меня в объекте ca, дальше мне нужно внести его в массив объектов и нужно еще один объект создать и внести туда, и так сколько угодно раз

Comment: И на будущее не используйте в названиях переменных, методов, классов и т д украинские, русские или какие-нибудь другие имена. Названия методов только на англ языке!

Answer (score 2):

В Java массив динамически не расширяется. Вы аллоцируете какой-то участок памяти под заполнение и, собственно, заполняете ). 
 К примеру:

`Object[] array = new Object[12];`

`Object[] array = new Object[]{ca};` - в этом конкретно случае вы создали массив длинной 1.

Если вы хотите дописать следующий элемент Вам стоит либо создать массив длинной `текущей + 1` и копировать ссылки из источника либо же обратиться к реализациям интерфейса java.util.Collection
Вам, скорее всего, подойдет [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - это как раз и есть готовая реализация динамически расширяемого (через перезапись) массива.

Answer (score 1):

Как отметил @PeterSlusar необходимо использовать `ArrayList`:

```
List<Cassa> cassaList = new ArrayList<>(); 
cassaList.add(ca1); 
cassaList.add(ca2);
```

Вывести можно так:

```
cassaList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> При условии, что переопределен метод `toString()` в `Cassa`